# fs.appendFile not appending the data in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What the following code does is to take a couple of text files from a folder and append them into a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
    , input = process.argv[2]

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME')
  process.exit(1)
}

fs.readdir(__dirname + `/${input}/`, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    return
  }

  files.forEach((file, index) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      let result

      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }

      if (index == files.length - 1) {
        result = `${data}`
      } else {
        result = `${data}\n`
      }

      fs.appendFile("merged.txt", result, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(result)
        }
      })
    })
  })
})
```

So let's say I have a folder called `docs` and inside there is doc1.txt, doc2.txt, doc3.txt`with the content`## Doc 1, ## Doc 2, and ## Doc 3`respectively. The code would produce a single file called`merged.txt` with the content:

```
## Doc 1

## Doc 2

## Doc 3
```

It works okay. But sometimes the order is wrong. I'll get something like:

```
## Doc 1

## Doc 3

## Doc 2
```

Especially when there are many files.

How can I modify the code to prevent this problem?

Comment: You're running a bunch of async operations in parallel.  There is no guaranteed execution order unless you manually sequence the operations to force a specific order of execution.

Comment: You're calling an async function (`appendFile`) inside a regular `forEach`, which is synchronous. There's no guarantee that the previous `appendFile` will have finished when the next one is called. Take a look at promises ([q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) or [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)) or even the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module.

Answer (score 1):

You could either change `fs.appendFile` to `fs.appendFileSync` (quick and dirty but not the best solution) or you could run the events in series using the `eachSeries` method of the `async` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#eachSeries).

Comment: Your first suggestion won't necessarily work either because `fs.readFile()` is still async.

Comment: Good point, I overlooked that. You'd have to change `fs.readFile` to `fs.readFileSync` as well, and adjust the code to not use the callbacks.